# Ubuntu 12.04 installation error in Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, boot

How can I fix this error?

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args
  - Check root delay= (did the system wait for long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing module (`cat/proc/modules; ls/dev`)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/3C50BC8050BC4286 does not exist does not exist.       
Dropping to shell!
```

Comment: please explain more about your problem. what are you doing. where this error shows up etc..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like partition faulty. You can try live CD or live USB to determine if you're able to rescue your partition or backup your data for new installation.